# Prestashop remove the call us info header

Tags: templates, header, task-parallel-library, prestashop

In which module and tpl file I can delete the "call us" info and number phone that appear in the Header template I'm using?

Using Prestashop 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your themes-> your theme -> modules -> block contact -> nav.tpl edit this file.

Answer (score 3):

There are two contact modules pre-installed
`Contact information block` (displays in the footer)
and
`Contact block` (displays in the header)
You just need to remove the phone number in the module `Contact block` (leave the field empty)